# How can i have 8 input video signals on one screen

Tags: video, multiplexing

I have 5 video siganls coming from diff cameras. I want that i can attach them to one system which can show me all cameras on one TV screen

I forget what to call that system so that i can find on internet

```
Like 8 video input ---------->One AV video output--TV screen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for device like this - http://www.euroworld-international.co.uk/cctv-8-camera-quad-multiplexer-splitter--remote-1346-p.asp